# Compute the angle of the tangent line to space defined by a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, angle, tangent-line

I"m taking multivariable calculus and I'm being given the curve  $\vec{r}(t)= e^t \textbf{i} + (cos^2t + 1) \textbf{j} + (-t^2 + t - 1) \textbf{k}$, the point $P_0 = \vec{r}(0)$ and the yz-plane. I literally have no idea how to compute for the angle of the tangent line to the space defined by that curve. Do I just take the derivative?

Comment: What does the $y$-$z$ plane have to do with anything?

Comment: The angle between the tangent line and what?

Comment: Apparently it was the angle between the tangent line and the yz-plane, professor worded it very oddly